# pipefail over ssh in linux

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh

set -o pipefail is not getting evaluated correctly on the remote host if the set command is used in ssh command.
Example
ssh hostname "set -o pipefail; false | true; echo $?" - gives 0 (Not expected)
ssh hostname 'set -o pipefail; false | true; echo $?' - gives 1 (Expected)

How do we evaluate the set commands correctly on the remote hosts when commands are enclosed with double quotes. I will have to use the local variables in ssh commands, so double quotes are required

Answer (score 1):

> I will have to use the local variables in ssh commands, so double quotes are required

That's precisely the problem you're having: you are allowing your shell to expand `$?` as if a local variable. The `set` commands are evaluated correctly, but their effect is not visible because the command that follows is just `echo 0`, not `echo $?`.

So you need a mix of local and remote expansion, i.e. `"echo \$?"` using backslash escaping where appropriate.

---

(On a mostly unrelated note, when you're using local expansion to build up a remote command, the `${var@Q}` modifier – new in Bash 5.0 – is convenient to produce a correctly remote-quoted string; e.g. `ssh foo "bar -i ${baz@Q}"`.

Comment: Thank You ! It worked